# Tagwiki edit was accepted with only one review

Tags: support, tags, editing

Suggested edits (including tagwiki edits) by users who don't have enough reputation for their changes to show up immediately ([2,000 reputation for question/answer edits](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), [20,000 for tagwiki edits](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)) need two positive reviews to be accepted (with one exception: for a question/answer edit, a positive review by the author of the question/answer is sufficient for the edit to be accepted, even in the total absence of other reviews).

However, [this tagwiki edit of mine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44887) was accepted with but a single review.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 8):

> What went wrong?

Nothing.

♦ moderators have superpowers™. If a ♦ moderator accepts or rejects something, no other review is necessary.